# Problem with .htaccess for files having similar kind of names

Tags: htaccess, php, css, mod-rewrite

I have a file with name `lang.php` and another file in the same folder with same `lang_inst.php`.
The .htaccess am using is:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/lang folder/lang.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)folder/lang_inst/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) folder/lang_inst.php?lngid=$1&lngname=$2 [NC,L]
```

The problem is when I go to `lng.php` it is working well and good even if I type `lng.klklk` or `lng` we will be showing `lng.php` page only but when we try to view `lng_inst.php` page the we are getting the same content of `lng.php` page with total disturbed CSS.  I mean the total design CSS everything is missing.

I have tried creating same page with other names and it's working well and good. I don't want to rename or recreate pages because I have so many pages like that. I mean files starting with same words (like `sample.php` `sample_create.php`).

Please help me to fix this.Please.

Comment: "The problem is when I go to `lng.php`" - presumably, you're not actually including the `.php` extension at all in the request (that's the point of your rewrite). But your example code assumes a request for `/folder/lang`, not `lng.php`. If you exemplify your code, the description still nees to match, otherwise it just becomes confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A request for `lng_inst.php` will naturally get caught by the first, more generic, rule. You need to *reverse* your two rules, so the more *specific* rule is first.  For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)folder/lang_inst/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) folder/lang_inst.php?lngid=$1&lngname=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^folder/lang folder/lang.php [NC,L]
```

You also need to disable `MultiViews` (which will otherwise override your directive to rewrite `lang` to `lang.php`), if you haven't already:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
```

Alternatively, you could just make your first directive more specific (depending on your use case) and match *exactly* `folder/lang` and not any URL that *starts* with that URL. For example, change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to read: `^folder/lang$` (additional trailing `$`).

*Aside:* Only use the `NC` (`nocase`) flag if you specifically need a case-insensitive match. For a *rewrite*, this is probably not the case, since you potentially create a duplicate content issue.